# Exportar arquivo XPDL no Camunda Modeler

Tags: modelagem, exportação

Alguém sabe se  é possível exportar um arquivo no formato XPDL a partir de um diagrama feito no Camunda Modeler?

Comment: o que vc já fez? faça um [Tur] (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)